# How do I determine a movable area in game squares

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a turn based HTML game based on a 2D square grid.  Each grid square could take a variable number of movement points to cross (IE: 1 MP for roads, 1.5 MP for grasslands, 2 MP for forests, etc).  When the user clicks on a unit I want to determine all possible movable spaces with said unit's allotted movement points so that I can highlight them and make them clickable.

Is there a free library available to do this?  I've seen a few pathing algorithms but nothing about determining movable area.  How do other game developers handle this problem?  I'm open to both vanilla JS and JQuery solutions.

Comment: Try [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I decided to try and attack this myself.  I've never been great at these sorts of algorithms so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to handle it than what I've done.  However, for my purposes it runs quickly enough and is very simple and easy to understand.

In case it's helpful to anyone else looking to do the same, I've included the code below.  This is an updated version of my original answer, which I modified to also store the path taken so that you can show the units moving through the correct spaces.  This answer uses JQuery in the lower examples, but only in a few places; you can easily enough replace them with vanilla JS.  And the first block of code, containing the actual path/area finding functionality, is pure JS.

```
<script>
    var possibleMovementAreaArray   = new Array();  // This array will hold our allowable movement tiles.  Your other functions can access this after running possibleMovementArea().

    function possibleMovementArea(unitIndex) {
        // I'm storing each unit in my game in an array.  So I pass in the index of the unit I want to determine the movement area for.
        var x   = unitList[unitIndex][10];  // x coordinate on the playgrid
        var y   = unitList[unitIndex][11];  // y coordinate on the playgrid
        var mp  = unitList[unitIndex][15];  // number of movement points
        possibleMovementAreaArray.length = 0;  // Clear our array so previous runs don't interfere.

        findPossibleMovement(x, y, mp);
    }

    function findPossibleMovement(x, y, mp, prevStepX, prevStepY) {
        // This is a recursive function; something I'm not normally too good at.

        for (var d=1; d<=4; d++) {
            // We run through each of the four cardinal directions.  Bump this to 8 and add 4 more cases to include corners.
            if (d == 1) {
                // Check Up
                var newX = x;
                var newY = y - 1;
            } else if (d == 2) {
                // Check Down
                var newX = x;
                var newY = y + 1;
            } else if (d == 3) {
                // Check Left
                var newX = x - 1;
                var newY = y;
            } else if (d == 4) {
                // Check Right
                var newX = x + 1;
                var newY = y;
            }

            // Check to see if this square is occupied by another unit.  Two units cannot occupy the same space.
            spaceOccupied = false;
            for (var j=1; j<=numUnits; j++) {
                if (unitList[j][10] == newX && unitList[j][11] == newY)
                    spaceOccupied = true;
            }

            if (!spaceOccupied) {
                // Modify this for loop as needed for your usage.  I have a 2D array called mainMap that holds the ID of a type of terrain for each tile.
                // I then have an array called terList that holds all the details for each type of terrain, such as movement points needed to get past.
                // This for loop is just looking up the ID of the terrain for use later.  Sort of like a "SELECT * FROM terrainInfo WHERE ID=terrainOfCurrentTile".
                for (var j=1; j<=numTerrains; j++) {
                    if (newX > 0 && newX <= mapWidth && newY > 0 && newY <= mapHeight && terList[j][1] == mainMap[newX][newY])
                        break;  // After finding the index of terList break out of the loop so j represents the correct index.
                }
                if (j <= numTerrains) {  // Run if an actual terrain is found.  No terrain is found if the search runs off the sides of the map.
                    var newMp   = mp - terList[j][7];  // Decrement the movement points for this particular path.
                    if (newMp >= 0) {  // Only continue if there were enough movement points to move to this square.
                        // Check to see if this square is already logged.  For both efficiency and simplicity we only want each square logged once.
                        var newIndex                            = possibleMovementAreaArray.length
                        var alreadyLogged = false
                        if (possibleMovementAreaArray.length > 0) {
                            for (var j=0; j<possibleMovementAreaArray.length; j++) {
                                if (possibleMovementAreaArray[j][1] == newX && possibleMovementAreaArray[j][2] == newY) {
                                    alreadyLogged           = true;
                                    var alreadyLoggedIndex  = j;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!alreadyLogged) {
                            // This adds a row to the array and records the x and y coordinates of this tile as movable
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex]     = new Array(6);
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex][1]  = newX;
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex][2]  = newY;
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex][3]  = prevStepX;  // This tracks the x coords of the steps taken so far to get here.
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex][4]  = prevStepY;  // This tracks the y coords of the steps taken so far to get here.
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[newIndex][5]  = newMp;  // Records remaining MP after the previous steps have been taken.
                        }
                        if (alreadyLogged && newMp > possibleMovementAreaArray[alreadyLoggedIndex][5]) {
                            // If this tile was already logged, but there was less MP remaining on that attempt, then this one is more efficient.  Update the old path with this one.
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[alreadyLoggedIndex][3]    = prevStepX;
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[alreadyLoggedIndex][4]    = prevStepY;
                            possibleMovementAreaArray[alreadyLoggedIndex][5]    = newMp;
                        }
                        if (newMp > 0) {
                            // Now update the list of previous steps to include this tile.  This list will be passed along to the next call of this function, thus building a path.
                            if (prevStepX == '') {
                                var newPrevStepX = [newX];
                                var newPrevStepY = [newY];
                            } else {
                                // This code is required to make a full copy of the array holding the existing list of steps.  If you use a simple equals then you just create a reference and
                                // subsequent calls are all updating the same array which creates a chaotic mess.  This way we store a separate array for each possible path.
                                var newPrevStepX = prevStepX.slice();
                                newPrevStepX.push(newX);
                                var newPrevStepY = prevStepY.slice();
                                newPrevStepY.push(newY);
                            }

                            // If there are still movement points remaining, check and see where we could move next.
                            findPossibleMovement(newX, newY, newMp, newPrevStepX, newPrevStepY);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

After running the above, you can then loop through the array to find all usable tiles.  Here is how I did it:

```
<script>
    // Shows the movement area based on the currently selected unit.
    function showMovement() {
        var newHTML = "";
        curAction   = "move";
        possibleMovementArea(curUnit);  // See above code
        for (x=0; x<possibleMovementAreaArray.length; x++) {
            // Loop over the array and do something with each tile.  In this case I'm creating an overlay that I'll fade in and out.
            var tileLeft    = (possibleMovementAreaArray[x][1] - 1) * mapTileSize;  // Figure out where to absolutely position this tile.
            var tileTop     = (possibleMovementAreaArray[x][2] - 1) * mapTileSize;  // Figure out where to absolutely position this tile.
            newHTML = newHTML + "<img id='path_" + possibleMovementAreaArray[x][1] + "_" + possibleMovementAreaArray[x][2] + "' onClick='mapClk(" + possibleMovementAreaArray[x][1] + ", " + possibleMovementAreaArray[x][2] + ", 0);' src='imgs/path.png' class='mapTile' style='left:" + tileLeft + "px; top:" + tileTop + "px;'>";
        }
        $("#movementDiv").html(newHTML);  // Add all those images into a preexisting div.
        $("#movementDiv").css("opacity", "0.5");  // Fade the div to 50%
        $("#movementDiv").show();  // Make the div visible.
        startFading();  // Run a routine to fade the div in and out.
    }
</script>
```

Since we determined the path, we can easily show movement as well by looping through the stored information:

```
<script>
    for (j=0; j<possibleMovementAreaArray[areaIndex][3].length; j++) {
        // This loop moves the unit img to each tile on its way to its destination.  The final destination tile is not included.
        var animSpeed   = 150;  // Time in ms that it takes to move each square.
        var animEase    = "linear"; // We want movement to remain a constant speed through each square in this case.
        var targetLeft  = (possibleMovementAreaArray[areaIndex][3][j]-1) * mapTileSize; // This looks at each step in the path array and multiplies it by tile size to determine the new horizonal position.
        var targetTop   = (possibleMovementAreaArray[areaIndex][4][j]-1) * mapTileSize; // This looks at each step in the path array and multiplies it by tile size to determine the new vertical position.
        $("#char_"+curUnit).animate({"left":targetLeft, "top":targetTop}, animSpeed, animEase);  // Do the animation.  Subsequent animations get queued.                
    }

    // Now we need to move to that last tile.
    newLeft = (x-1) * mapTileSize;
    newTop  = (y-1) * mapTileSize;
    $("#char_"+curUnit).animate({"left":newLeft, "top":newTop}, 400, "easeOutCubic");  // Slow unit at the end of journey for aesthetic purposes.

    $("#char_"+curUnit).addClass("unitMoved", 250); // Turns the image grayscale so it can easily be seen that it has already moved.
</script>
```

Hopefully this is helpful to others.